# query get data from one table and join other data from 2 tables where the same ID

Tags: mysql, query

This query get data from table products and JOIN data from product_details  with rule check the same product ID.

```
$query = "SELECT p.id, 
                 p.slug, 
                 p.sku, 
                 p.price, 
                 p.vat_rate, 
                 p.stock, 
                 p.brand, 
                 p.ean, 
                 p.gender, 
                 pd.title, 
                 pd.description 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_details pd ON p.id = pd.id
WHERE p.stock >= 50";
```

I need also JOIN data from table images  value: image_default and I also need check and JOIN for the same product ID but not working.

```
$query = "SELECT p.id, 
                 p.slug, 
                 p.sku, 
                 p.price, 
                 p.vat_rate, 
                 p.stock, 
                 p.brand, 
                 p.ean, 
                 p.gender, 
                 pd.title, 
                 pd.description,
                 pd.image_default 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_details, images pd ON p.id = pd.id
WHERE p.stock >= 50";
```

I try some like but something went wrong.

Comment: *I try some like but something went wrong.*,please post the full error. `INNER JOIN product_details, images` this is not valid. Please read [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and update the question.

Comment: "something went wrong" --> System crashed?  Your child wet himself?  A tornado hit?